# how can I get cell td into controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I use tempate of jquery to build my table.  When a user click on one cell of my table, I add attribute "name" on this cell.

I would like retrieve which cell is clicked and with which value but i not successful to retrieve my value cell into controller asp mvc.
I use FormCollection but i not find my cell td and i try also a request.form["cellTd"] but it's not work.
Into my controller, cell equals null and form not contains the elements cellTd.

Thanks for your help.

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Test", FormMethod.Post ))
{
<div id="TableToFill"></div>
<button id="send" value="send" name="btn" type="submit">send</button>
}
```

My template:

```
<script id="TableTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<table class="Table">
<tbody class="BodyTable"> 
    {{each list}}
    <tr class="Item">    
        <td description="Standard${Name}" >${this.Value}</td>
        {{if $index == 0}}
        <td ><input description="high${Name}" value="" type="text" /></td>
        {{/if}}
    </tr>    
    {{/each}}  
</tbody>
</table>       
</script>
```

My code jquery

```
<script type="javascript">
$.getJSON("getTable", params, function (items) {
        $("#TableTemplate").tmpl(items).appendTo("#TableToFill");        
    });
    $(".Table tbody .Item td").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("name","cellTd");
    });
</script>
```

My controller

```
public class TestController : controller
{
    public ActionResult(FormCollection form)
    {
        String cell=Request.Form["cellTd"];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ropstah , i have multi tables with multiselected to send in my controller. it's not possible to send with a simple input? Otherwise i create a function who send all elements who have a name...

Comment: What is the exact value you would like to receive in your controller?

Comment: @Ropstah I would like recieve all elements with attributes names filled. I have different values into my cells, i have a simple text(string or int) or a balise img( I add a attributes 'description' on balise img for know the value of the image)

Answer (score 0):

You should send your request inside the `click` event of the `td`:

```
$(".Table tbody .Item td").click(function(){
    //you are setting the name to "CellTd"
    $(this).attr("name", "cellTd");

    var tdNameValue = $(this).attr("name"); //will always give "cellTd" as it is set above...

    //make your ajax request here
    $.ajax({
       url: 'urltocontroller',
       data: {tdName : tdNameValue},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(r) {
           //successcallback
       },
       type: 'POST'
    });
});
```

Now you can retrieve your value here:

```
public class TestController : controller
{
    public ActionResult(FormCollection form)
    {
        String cell=Request.Form["cellTd"];
    }
}
```